# MS Graph create teams meeting Bad Request "onlinemeeting cannot be null."

Tags: java, json, azure, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to create a meeting through a web app using a HttpPost request, but I'm getting a 400 BadRequest error with the message "onlinemeeting cannot be null."

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings");
        
LocalDateTime meetingTime = java.time.LocalDateTime.now();
        
try {
    JSONObject bodyJson = new JSONObject();
        
    bodyJson.put("meetingType", "meetNow"); //tried with and without this and still didn't work
    bodyJson.put("startDateTime", meetingTime.toString());
    bodyJson.put("subject", "TeamsMeeting");
    bodyJson.put("participants", new JSONObject().put("organizer", 
            new JSONObject().put("identity", 
                    new JSONObject().put("user", 
                            new JSONObject().put("id", userId)))));
    
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(bodyJson.toString());
    entity.setContentType("application/json");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            
    BasicHeader authHeader = new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + teamsToken);
    httpPost.addHeader(authHeader);
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        
            
    HttpResponse postResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    String responseContent = EntityUtils.toString(postResponse.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
...
```

I get this when executing the post request:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code":"BadRequest",
        "message":"onlinemeeting cannot be null.",
        "innerError": {
            "date":"2020-07-10T19:09:48",
            "request-id":"cfad7871-6595-4efb-a262-13ac42f0e599"
        }
    }
}
```

It works when I use postman, but I can't when hitting it through my webapp. Any ideas what might be causing this? Is there something wrong in the Java code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being with the startDateTime because I think it wasn't in the exact format required. The error message didn't indicate that it was that value, but once removing that from the json body, it worked without having to use the OnlineMeeting object.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an online meeting with **user token**, there is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#request) of `OnlineMeeting` with Java in MS Graph.

```
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

OnlineMeeting onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting();
onlineMeeting.startDateTime = "2019-07-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00";
onlineMeeting.endDateTime = "2019-07-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00";
onlineMeeting.subject = "User Token Meeting";

graphClient.me().onlineMeetings()
    .buildRequest()
    .post(onlineMeeting);
```

If you create an online meeting with **application token**, try this code:

```
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

OnlineMeeting onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting();
onlineMeeting.startDateTime = "2019-07-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00";
onlineMeeting.endDateTime = "2019-07-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00";
onlineMeeting.subject = "Application Token Meeting";

MeetingParticipants meetingParticipants = new MeetingParticipants();
meetingParticipants.organizer.identity.user.id = "550fae72-d251-43ec-868c-373732c2704f";
onlineMeeting.participants = meetingParticipants;


graphClient.me().onlineMeetings()
.buildRequest()
.post(onlineMeeting);
```

For more details about the Class `OnlineMeeting`, see [here](https://javadoc.io/static/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph/1.7.1/com/microsoft/graph/models/extensions/OnlineMeeting.html).

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I was hoping to use an HttpPost request to avoid importing the Microsoft class, but I'll check it out and see if that works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code its worked for me:

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(authHelper.getMsGraphEndpointHost() + url)
          .post(body)
          .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
          .addHeader("authorization", accessToken)
          .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
          .build();

        Response responseOk = client.newCall(request).execute();
```